# Hibernate search query for id and object value not working as expected

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a structure like this:

```
@Indexed
class MainObject {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;

@IndexedEmbedded
@OneToMany
List<ObjectLevel1> objectLevel1 ;
}

@Indexed
class ObjectLevel1 {


@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "", nullable = false)
@IndexedEmbedded
ObjectLevel2 objectLevel2;

@Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO)
Long value;
}

class ObjectLevel2 {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id
}
```

FullTextQuery is created for MainObject.class

When I query +(+objectLevel1.objectLevel2.id:141 +objectLevel1.value:5) I'm expecting to get only these result which exactly have objectLevel1.value and and objectLevel1.objectLevel2.id, but I'm getting mixed results, like objectLevel1.value OR objectLevel1.objectLevel.id

How to query for get result which satisfy this 2 conditions?

EDIT: updated annotations for model and added below query code:

```
 q1.add(new TermQuery(new Term("objectLevel1.objectLevel2.id", s
                        .getValue().toString())), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

 q1.add(new TermQuery(new Term(
                            "objectLevel1.value", s.getValue()
                                    .toString())), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);


 query.add(q1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Comment: Can you also add the actual annotations or the programmatic configuration? How do you write your query? The programmatic search DSL or native Lucene query?

Comment: I updated my post with annotations and queries